# Can we enforce certain aws tags on CloudFormation stack(level) via Tagging policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

can we enforce certain tags to be used while deploying the CloudFormation stack such that if someone doesn't provide those tags, they won't be able to deploy the stack in an AWS account?

what I am trying to do is to enforce certain tag patterns. for example, if anyone wants to deploy their stack they have to provide certain tags like

1. Project_Name
2. Owner
3. Stage

and further, is there any way we can enforce this tagging(to CloudFormation tags) at an org level via Tagging policy? so nobody can deploy those stacks if they haven't have those tags on stack level.

what this will does is it will enforce tagging on a stack level rather than resources' level. Since stacks can have multiple resources inside and you don't want to use the same tag under each resource. so we can require certain tags on the stack deployment level.

I do know that we can create a service control policy(SCP) for the AWS organization but can we use a tag policy for this use-case? and is that the right solution to implement this or is there any better way we can do this?

Comment: Looks like you can't enforce tagging on a stack level. enforce tagging supports limited AWS resources and CloudFormation isn't on the supported resorces list. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_supported-resources-enforcement.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply SCP to enforce the inclusion of Tags on creation of CloudFormation Stacks.
It is the right approach if you want to restrict it at the account level. If you want to apply specifically to a user or group then SCP it is not suitable.
Test with the following SCP. You can add so many conditions as you want:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "CloudformationForceTagProject",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Project_Name": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "CloudformationForceTagOwner",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "CloudformationForceTagStage",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "cloudformation:CreateStack",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/Stage": "true"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```